# table.sort in Lua: Don't Understand this Code?

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

```
  -- original table
  t = {
    Steve = 20,
    Mary = 32,
    Tim = 15
  }

  --second table to help sort t{}    
  a = {}
  for n in pairs(t) do
    a[#a + 1] = n -- I do not completely understand this line.  
                  -- I know [#a + 1] is the iterator, but 
                  -- not a[#a + 1] and why equal that to "n"?
  end
  table.sort(a)
  for _, n in ipairs(a) do -- I do not understand the point of the underscore 
    print (n)
  end

  -- another way to perform the table.sort function        
  function pairsByKeys (t,f)
    local b = {}
    for x in pairs (t) do 
      b[#b + 1] = x
    end
    table.sort(b, f)
    local i = 0
    return function ()
      i = i + 1
      return b[i], t[b[i]]  -- I do not understand this line either?
    end
  end
```

I've placed the couple of questions I have in the comments that follow the specific code.  I understand (for the most part) why the need for two separate tables.  One has the information, the other to sort that information via `ipairs`.  I know the difference between `pairs` and `ipairs`.  But I do not clearly understand `a[#a + 1] = n`.  Also, I do not understand the code `for _, n in ipairs(a)`..., why the underscore?  Finally, I do not clearly understand the line `return b[i], t[b[i]]`?

Can you guys please help me understand the table.sort a bit better?  These are direct examples from the PiL.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: `a[#a + 1] = n` is adding element to the end of table (since `#a` is length of `a`). `_` is often used as dummy variable - nothing special about it really, we are just not interested in it's value.

Comment: Your edit seems like a new question, then I suggest you posting a new question.

Comment: @Yu Hao: ok.  I was worried about it being told that this is in relation to my previous topic so to post there.  I will do so and remove my edit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should understand what Lua tables really are. On the surface they appear as *associative arrays* or *maps* (two widely known CS terms), which often are implemented as *hash tables*. They are called this way because they associate a so-called *key* (which is unique), with a *value*. They can be viewed as collections of key-value pairs indexed by the key, i.e. implemented in such a way that using the (unique) key you can find the corresponding value very quickly.

The two main peculiarities of Lua tables, which also make them really powerful and flexible data structures (although a bit tricky to understand fully at first), are the following:

1. Lua tables allow **any** kind of value (except, `nil`) as key. In most languages keys are restricted to be strings, or to be of a specific type that must be declared in advance. In Lua a table can hold any kind of value as key in any moment. Thus a table defined like this is perfectly legal in Lua:

   ```
   f = function(x) return x*x end
   t = { 1, 2, 3 }    
   tbl = {
       [t] = true,   -- `t` is the key (and a table), `true` is the value
       [f] = 12,     -- `f` is the key (and a function), `12` is the value
       [true] = f,   -- `true` is the key (boolean), `f` now is used as value
       [12] = f,     -- `12` is the key (number), `f` again as the value
       ["yup"] = t,  -- `"yup"` is the key (string), `t` now is used as value
   }
   ```
2. Positive integer keys have a special status, since hey are used to simulate *arrays*. Lua has no proper concept of *array*. In Lua we use *array-like tables* (a.k.a. *sequences*, using new Lua 5.2 terminology). Many times when you see the term *array* in the context of Lua, actually the writer means *array-like table*, and I'll do the same in the following for the sake of simplicity when no ambiguity could arise. What is an array in Lua? It is a table whose positive integer keys start at `1` and end at some integer `n`, i.e. whose positive integer keys are only the numbers 1, 2, ..., n (another way to say this is to say that the positive integer keys form the set {1, 2,...,n}). That number `n` is called the *length of the sequence (array)* and it is the number returned by the `#` operator when applied to an array. If a table has this property it is called a *sequence*, i.e. can be referred to as an array. Note that a table with that property is still an array if:

   - it has additional non-numeric keys (e.g. string or table keys);
   - it has additional numeric keys that are non integer (e.g. `1.23`);
   - it has additional integer keys that are non-positive (e.g. `0` or `-12`).

The distinction between a "generic table" and an array is not only a terminology convenience. Under the hood Lua implementation recognizes if a table is indeed an array and performs some optimizations that allow a Lua table to have high performance when using an array-like table as an array (as meant in C, for example). In fact Lua standard `table` library assumes that the tables fed to its functions (like `table.sort`) are indeed arrays, and operate only on the entries that have positive integer indexes.

---

With all that in mind we can analyze the difficult points in the code you posted.

```
a = {}
for n in pairs(t) do
  a[#a + 1] = n 
end
```

This is an example of a generic for-loop. `pairs` returns (among other things) the table iterator function (so `pairs` and `ipairs` could be called *iterator generating functions* or *iterator generators*). This iterator function is repeatedly called by the `for` machinery to iterate over all the keys (and the corresponding values) of `t`. Since only one variable appear in the `for` (namely `n`), just the keys of `t` are retrieved during the iteration.

```
a[#a + 1] = n
```

is just a quick way to append the key stored in `n` to the table `a`, which turns out to be an array, since it is built step-by-step during the iteration to have only sequential positive integer keys starting from 1. Remember that `#a` is the current length of `a` (which is initially `0`, since `a` has no entries), thus `a[#a+1]` creates a new entry with an integer key `#a + 1` without disrupting the *sequence property* of `a`.

To summarize, that `for` loop simply collects all the keys of `t` in an array `a` in order to sort them using `table.sort` and then print them:

```
table.sort(a)
for _, n in ipairs(a) do 
    print (n)
end
```

The previous is another example of generic for. In this case the iterator function returned by `ipairs` will return both the (positive integer) keys and the values of `a` during the iteration (in this order). Since we are interested only in printing the values (the keys will be `1`, `2`, ... etc., since `a` is an array), we use `_` as a dummy variable to get the (to us irrelevant) key. We could have used another name, but it is idiomatic in Lua to use the (perfectly legal and normal) name `_` for this task.

---

The definition of `pairsByKeys` is a bit more difficult to analyze. Its purpose is to have an iterator generator (`pairsByKeys`) returning an iterator function that can iterate over a table guaranteeing that the iteration is done according to a specific key order (Lua `pairs` doesn't guarantee any specific order of iteration). It is meant to be used like this:

```
for k, v in pairsByKeys( t ) do
    print( k, v )
end
```

Let's analyze the definition. We'll see that it packs in a single function the logic of the code we have already analyzed (plus an enhancement).

```
function pairsByKeys(t,f)
    local b = {}
    for x in pairs(t) do
      b[#b + 1] = x
    end
    table.sort(b, f)
    local i = 0
    return function()
      i = i + 1
      return b[i], t[b[i]] 
    end
end
```

The first thing to note is that `pairsByKeys` returns a function (the iterator), which actually is an anonymous closure with three upvalues (`i`, `t` and `b`). This means that the returned function will be able to reference these three variables when it will be executed by the `for` machinery (this closure is an example of *stateful* iterator).

Before returning the iterator, `pairsByKeys` "preprocesses" the table to be iterated `t` extracting its keys and sorting them as we have already seen above. Thus `b` will hold all the keys of `t` in the order in which `table.sort(b,f)` will place them. Note that this call to `table.sort` has an additional argument `f`, which is a comparator function that can be specified when calling `pairsByKeys`. This allows to sort the keys according to different criteria (this is the "enhancement" I told you about).

the `i` variable will hold the index of the key in `b` that has just been iterated over. Since at this stage no iteration has taken place (the iterator has not been created, yet).

Let's focus now on the iterator function:

```
function()
  i = i + 1
  return b[i], t[b[i]] 
end
```

whenever this is called by the `for` machinery, it will increment `i`, then it will fetch `b[i]`, which is the next key to be iterated (it takes it from `b` since it's `b` that holds the information about their ordering), then it uses `b[i]` again to fetch the corresponding value `t[b[i]]` from the original table `t`, which holds this information. Both key and values are returned and these two values are those that are assigned (in each iteration) to the loop variables `k` and `v` of the example above, which then prints them.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for the very detailed answer.  I would actually like to thank everyone who has helped me with this.  I have created tables to answer the first few questions on Project Euler and understand `a[#a+1]` as I had to take answers and return them to the `a[]`.  But I was unsure why you perform the rest of my questions.  You guys have all greatly aided in my understanding of tables a more.  I know now what to do to get some practice on them. Thank you all!!!  I'm sorry I can't make everyone's post an answer or I would!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
  --second table to help sort t{}    
  a = {}
  for n in pairs(t) do
    a[#a + 1] = n  
  end
```

`[#a + 1]` is *not* an iterator -- that's an index access to a specific element in the table. `#a` is the table size. By adding +1 to this you are accessing *one past* the last element in the table. This operation is appending `n` to the end of table `a` in the loop.

This is the same as doing:

```
  table.insert(a, n)
```

---

```
for _, n in ipairs(a) do -- I do not understand the point of the underscore 
-- ...
```

The underscore here is just use to represent an unused variable. `_` is a valid lua variable but it doesn't have any special meaning in lua. You could have named it `dummy` instead and it wouldn't make a difference here.

That dummy is needed here because `pairs` and `ipairs` returns a key followed by a value. This code wants to 'skip-over' the key and just use the value.

---

```
  -- ...
    return function ()
      i = i + 1
      return b[i], t[b[i]]  -- I do not understand this line either?
    end
```

That's an anonymous closure that returns 2 values when it gets called. `b[i]` is the next element in table `b`. `t[b[i]]` is accessing a value in `t` using `b[i]` as the key.

The more explicit steps would look like this:

```
    return function ()
      i = i + 1
      local nextkey = b[i]
      local nextvalue = t[nextkey]
      return nextkey, nextvalue
    end
```

Comment: "This is the same as doing: `table.insert(a, n)`" -> it serves the same purpose, but the generated code is not equivalent. There can also be performance implications (notably, the lack of additional look-ups)

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1

```
for n in pairs(t) do
    a[#a + 1] = n
end
```

The `#` operator returns the number of elements in the table (actually it only returns the highest numerical index in the table, but in this example it makes no difference). Inside this loop, `n`  is the first value (of the pair of values) returned from `pairs(t)`, which is the key of the current element in the table. Thus, the code can be seen as evaluating to this:

```
a[1] = 'Steve'
a[2] = 'Mary'
a[3] = 'Tim'
```

## Question 2

```
for _, n in ipairs(a) do
```

The underscore here is a Lua convention for when the index value of `ipairs` is not desired. It can be seen as a side-effect of Lua's ability to return multiple values from a function. The first value actually gets stored in a variable called `_` but the programmer is purposefully making no use of it.